# Mathematical competitions for adults.

Tags: reference-request, education

I live in Mexico city. However, I am not so interested in whether these exist in my vicinity but want to learn if they exist, if they do then It might be easier to make them more popular in other places.

Are there mathematical competitions for adults? I have been into a couple of mathematical competitions and they are fun. However, its sort of a race against the clock because you only have a couple of chances until you are too old. Are there mathematical competitions for people of all ages. I have looked this up but found none. It makes sense to separate people from second grade and 7th grade. But: for example in sports once it comes to adults they separate them in different leagues. This could work to make it fair for mathematicians and mathematics enthusiasts alike.

Thanks for your answer.

PS When I say adults I mean people who need not still be studying in college, it includes people who have regular jobs.

Comment: It's not a contest for all ages as you describe, but the [Putnam contest](http://math.scu.edu/putnam/) is a math contest for college-age students such as yourself.

Comment: You can find some at [**MAA**](http://amc.maa.org/). You can also find a nice list with age ranges on the [**Wiki - List of mathematics competitions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_competitions#United_States) (make sure to look at the International and Regional examples there too!). Regards

Comment: @amzoti I didnt find any for adults

Comment: @Khromonkey, I thought you said you were 17 and assumed were looking for that age bracket. Were you looking for older adults than that?

Comment: Yes sorry, I might have confused people with that.

Comment: I found the mental calculation olympiad but I dont really count that as mathematics

Comment: There are some college level ones listed on [**SIAM**](http://www.siam.org/publicawareness/competitions.php).

Comment: For timed competitions open to all ages, I can only think of examples that lean heavily toward the computer science side.  Google Code Jam tends to be very mathematical (past the qualifying round), and IIT Hyderabad hosts the Felicity Mathematika contest.  Emphasis is on getting working solutions rather than proofs (quite understandable given that these are held over the Internet).

Comment: It would be prudent to specify you geographic location, as it may have some impact on what competitions you are eligible to participate in... I know it says that you're from Mexico in your profile, but you shouldn't have people fishing there for information.

Comment: @tomasz I live in Mexico city but I am pretty sure there arent any in Mexico, however I am interested in knowing if anyone has come up with this idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I know only one. I was looking for the same thing and found your question.

"Championnat International des Jeux Mathématiques et Logiques" 
http://www.animath.fr/spip.php?article595

Questions and answers must be in french. But there is no requirement for participation. Any age and nationalities are welcome.

Questions won't be translated for you, but I'm pretty sure that, if you answer in english graders won't mind. Just ask. ;)