# Why are there no recreational math events for adults?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Possibly off topic because it's about mathematical community rather than mathematics directly.

Assuming that the answer to [Mathematical competitions for adults.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267416/mathematical-competitions-for-adults) is still up to date...

### The motivation:

I recently become involved with preparing junior high aged kids for mathletics events. It rekindled my own interest in considering tough problems, so I decided to sit in on a practice session for my local university's Putnam group. I enjoyed that as well.

And now I'm stuck for what to do next.

I do intend to continue my own recreational exploration, and I'm interested in setting up some regular sessions for practicing and collaborating with local problem solvers, but these activities are missing the excitement of  the clock and the fun competitive nature of the competitions I wrote as a kid. I'm confident that there are lots of people out there who have as much interest in this sort of thing as myself.

### The question(s):

- Why are there no math competitions for unrestricted audiences?
- What makes preparing and administrating contests for students a higher priority than doing the same for general audiences?
- What organizations might take on such a task?

Comment: I can imagine an unrestricted math competition becoming an informal gathering for crackpots. Perhaps that's a little too cynical; but whoever is holding such a contest has effectively no power to stop it becoming something like that, and their only recourse would be to dissolve the contest.

Comment: Also, I would like to add that while the Putnam is limited to students, you are welcome to try it on your own, and good luck. It's challenging for anyone -- I can't really see a way to "scale up" the Putnam for adults.

Comment: For clarification, I'm not wanting a contest that's harder than the Putnum. In fact, I'd aim for a wider range of difficulty (eg, the easiest questions on Contest X being more accessible than the easiest Putnum questions).

Comment: And as for crackpots, lots of university students write the Putnam exactly once...

Comment: As a side note, there exists a individual problem-solving event called "Control Sum" ("Контрольная сумма"), organised by the Novosibirsk State University. The level of problems is close to final exams at russian secondary school, but the contest is open to everyone. Professional mathematicians get the perfect score and pass with flying colors, of course, but the results of general audience fit quite well the gaussian bell.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of our culture.  By the time we are adults we have made up our mind as to whether we are "good" at math or not.  It's no longer seen as something that we can improve at.  And with jobs and kids, there isn't that much time to change if we'd like to.

There is nothing stopping **you** from gathering a group of your friends and finding problems to solve.  There are no shortage of textbooks and problem books for you guys to work from.  Certainly you can look for inspiration here and on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/